# Open source thin-client software

Tags: linux, rdp, open-source, thin-client

I have been looking for a open source alternate to windows thin-client terminals we use for remote desktop into a terminal server which is where users do all their work.

I am often in the situation where i have multiple computers that would do great as a thin-client but i would need to buy an XP license.

Is there some kind of Linux software distro that basically lets you setup an automatic RDP connection on start-up?

Comment: Don't forget you'll still need to buy extra Server TS CALs for you terminal server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used it myself, but it sounds like [Thinstation](http://www.thinstation.org/) or maybe [Thintux](http://thintux.sourceforge.net/) is what you are looking for.

If you want to get more complicated, the [Linux Terminal Server Project](http://www.ltsp.org/) might be interesting also.

Comment: No need for complicated - LTSP is built right in to Ubuntu, just select the option from the boot CD's install screen

Comment: Thinstation works great and you can even PXE boot it to clients - no need for a harddisk install!

Answer (score 2):

Anything that can start [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/) will do this.  Set up an old pc with the linux distro of your choice and configure the users' .profile to start a rdesktop client.  Any of the knoppix custom kits would let you make a bootable CD that does this.

Answer (score 1):

tsclient works quite nicely manually. I haven't tried it, but the command accepts an rdp format file as well.